# woocommerce change order of meta boxes on Edit Product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The content for my Products is quite lengthy so it would be great to display the Product data (and Product short description) meta boxes above the Content Editor in the Edit Product page.

Seems simple and if ACF can do it ('High, below Title') I am sure that Woocommerce must be able to.

How do I reorder the admin metaboxes?

Comment: Drag to reorder ?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be wonderful if the answer was that simple?